# Find sequence so that linear functional converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

In $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, let $K = \bigcup_{k=2}^\infty F_k$ where $F_k = \{\log(k)e_j\}_{j=1}^{k}$ where $e_j = (0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, \ldots )\in \ell^2(n)$ with $1$ in the j$^\text{th}$ position. I want to show that for any $\phi \in (\ell^2)^*$, there is sequence $\{v_i\} \subset K$ such that $\phi(v_i)$ converges to $0$.

I know that for any $v\in K$, we can write $\phi(v) = \log(k) \phi(e_j)$ where $v = \log(k)e_j \in F_k \subset K$ for some $k \geq 2$ and $1 \leq j \leq k$. I also know that the sequence $\{\phi(e_j)\}$ also converges to $0$. However, I can't figure out how to choose elements in $K$ so that (intuitively speaking) the $\phi(e_j)$ decreases faster than $\log(k)$ increases.

I think we have $\sum |\phi(e_j)|^2 < \infty$ so this could ensure $\phi(e_j)$ decreases quickly enough but I don't know how to incorporate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_n=\phi(e_n).$ Then
$x\in \ell^2.$ As $(\log n)^{-1}\notin \ell^2$ there exists an increasing  subsequence $n_j$ of positive integers such that $(\log n_j ) |x_{n_j}|\le {1\over j}.$

**Explanation**
Indeed, assume by contradiction that such subsequence does not exist. Thus there exist $j_0$ and $n_0$ such that
$$(\log n ) |x_{n}|>{1\over j_0},\quad n\ge n_0$$
Hence
$$|x_{n}|> {1\over j_0}(\log n)^{-1},\quad n\ge n_0$$
and $$\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty|x_n|^2\ge {1\over j_0^2}\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty {1\over \log^2n}=\infty$$
which leads to a contradiction.

Returning to our reasoning, let $v_j=(\log n_j) e_{n_j}.$ Then $v_j\in K$ and $$|\varphi(v_j)|=(\log n_j)|x_{n_j}|\le {1\over j}$$ thus $\varphi(v_j)\underset{j\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0 .$

**Remark** The solution is valid if we replace $\log k$ with any sequence $a_k>0$ such that $(a_k^{-1})\notin \ell^2.$

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why $(\log n)^{-1} \notin \ell^2$ implies the existence of that subsequence? I can't seem to wrap my head around why it's true.

Comment: I have re-edited to add an explanation. Hopefully it is clearer now.